# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() while activating wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, php-8, php-closures

I got an error while activating a plugin in my WordPress website

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-options/includes/order-option-group.php:33 Stack trace: #0 /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-options/includes/order-option-group.php(364): Woocommerce_Product_Options_Order_Option_Group->__construct() #1 /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-options/woocommerce-product-options.php(22): require_once('/home4/seosexey...') #2 /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2314): include_once('/home4/seosexey...') #3 /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-admin/plugins.php(192): plugin_sandbox_scrape('woocommerce-pro...') #4 {main} thrown in /home4/seosexey/gifting.icowebtech.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-options/includes/order-option-group.php on line 33`

I guess I need to rewrite a code

```
$func = create_function( '',
                    'global $woocommerce_product_options_order_option_group; $woocommerce_product_options_order_option_group->print_order_options( "' . $location . '"); return;' );
            };
            add_action( $location, $func );
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: _"I guess I need to rewrite a code"_ - if this is not your _own_ plugin, that you yourself are maintaining - then you should rather update the plugin to a more current version, than manipulating plugin code yourself.

Comment: Could you add more context please? Like CBroe said, editing plugin content is a last last LAST resort. You don't want to have to maintain the plugin yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[create_function()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) has been removed from php 8. Cybercriminals found it far too easy to hack.

It's not necessary for the code you showed us. You can try using an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in your call to [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), like this. (Not debugged.)

```php
add_action( $location, function () use ( $location ) {
    global $woocommerce_product_options_order_option_group;
    $woocommerce_product_options_order_option_group->print_order_options
       ( $location );
    return;
});
```

The `use ( $location )` clause makes that variable from outside the function accessible inside the function.